# active class handle for parent/child routers in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Am new to aurelia, i have a main menu in left side, one of the menu(mail) is having sub-menus (inbox,sent,trash). i need to do if the sub menu is active(#current URL, #activeclass, #CSS ) needs to keep active class for the parent menu (mail).
**app.js**

export class App {

```
configureRouter(config, router){
    config.title = 'DMS';

    config.map([
        { route: ['dashboard',''],  name: 'Dashboard',
            moduleId: './templates/dashboard/dashboard',  nav: true, title:'Dashboard',settings:{'img' : 'ic-dashboard.png'} },
        { route: ['settings'],  name: 'Settings',
            moduleId: './templates/settings/settings',  nav: true, title:'Settings' ,settings:{'icon' : 'settings'} },
        { route: ['inbox'],  name: 'inbox',
            moduleId: './templates/mail/inbox/inbox',  nav: true, title:'Mail' ,settings:{'img' : 'mail.png'} },
        { route: ['inbox/trash'],  name: 'trash',
            moduleId: './templates/mail/trash/trash', title:'Mail' },
        { route: ['inbox/sent'],  name: 'sent',
            moduleId: './templates/mail/sent/sent', title:'Mail'},
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
}
```

**Menu list** also applying active class

```
<div class="row col s12 ${row.isActive ? 'active' : ''}" repeat.for = "row of router.navigation" >
        <a href.bind = "row.href">
        <div class="col s2 " >
            <div if.bind="row.settings.img">
                <img src="src/assets/${row.settings.img}">
            </div>
            <div if.bind="row.settings.icon">
                <i class="tiny material-icons">${row.settings.icon}</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**sub-menu url**

```
  <div class="col s8 offset-s2 mail_actionLst">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="inbox mail_active"><a href="#/inbox"> Inbox &nbsp; <span>(43)</span></a> </li>
                        <li class="sent"><a href="#/inbox/sent">Sent</a> </li>
                        <li class="trash"><a href="#/inbox/trash">Trash</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

[image: see URL and very left 'Mail' icon is in active then the 2nd pic looks like]

[image: Here u see the active class is gone while URL changes , still current URL(sent) is child for 'inbox'. I needs to keep mail icon active while URL in (inbox,sent,trash).]

How to set parent class active.

Answer (score 0):

Because these are different routes, not parent + children.
You should describe child route in parent class.
You can add code to `inbox.js`:

```js
configureRouter(config, router){

   config.map([
        { route: ['trash'],  name: 'trash',
            moduleId: 'path_to_trash', title:'Mail' },
        { route: ['sent'],  name: 'sent',
            moduleId: 'path_to_sent', title:'Mail'},
   ]);

   this.router = router;
  }
```

Don't forget to add 
`<router-view></router-view>`
to `inbox.html`.